# How do I put together this Python project structure?

Tags: python, structure, python-packaging, python-poetry

Say, I have this in mind:

```
myproject_root
|
|- myproject (*) [the project implementation]
|
|- myproject_plugins [extension modules for the project]
|  |- myproject_plugin1 (*)
|  |- myproject_plugin2 (*)
|  |- myproject_pluginN (*)
|
|- myproject_libraries [libraries, that I might need to use in `myproject_plugins`]
   |- library1 (*)
   |- library2 (*)
   |- library3 (*)
```

I would want to build a wheel for each starred (`*`) folder, preferrably by issuing a command in `myproject_root`.

I've tried using [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), but for the love of my life I couldn't find a way to construct a proper root pyproject.toml config that would support building a project like that. When building the root project, poetry tries to find a `myproject_root` folder, which I don't want to happen.

I'm willing to rewrite the whole build system with setup.py/requirements.txt, if need be.

Comment: Are all the "*starred*" directories supposed to each contain a separately (*pip*-) installable dependency? If yes, then each should have their own `pyproject.toml`.